Angular 18 - Is there an event that is generated by angular that indicate that the entire we page has been complete rendered. The entire page
ngAfterViewInit will be called for each component.
ngAfterViewChecked is called every time the view is "checked"
NavagationEnd is called many times.
Is there a SINGLE event that is called when all navigation/rendering/updates are complete for a web page?

Why do you need such a event? What's your purpose?

I assume, you dont only want to know when the html is rendered initially, but also when all data is fetched and correctly rendered. In order to do so, you need to have an observable in everyservice which emit when the data is loaded.
Put it in the wrapping component of your view inside the ngAfterViewInit().
I would go for an observable which can look like this:


combineLatest([
  loaded1$,
  loaded2$,
  loaded3$
]).pipe(
  filter(loaded => loaded.every(l => l)),
  take(1)
).subsribe(loaded => {
  // do whatever you want here
})



